# css distorting on adding Form tag

Tags: asp.net, css

I've following dummy HTML which properly displays a header, a left div (completely covering body) and a right div for contents. But as I add `<Form>` in ASPX page (or any html page) after body tag, my css formatting gets too much distorted. Please suggest.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title> 
    <style type="text/css">
body{
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

.leftNav {
background:red;
height:85%;
width:200px;
float:left;
}

.content{
background:orange;}

.header    {
height:15%;
background:blue;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<div class="header">dd</div>
<div class="leftNav">abcd</div>
<div class="content">asdasd<br>asdasd<p>asdasd</p>asd asifj sadjf</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Which css gets distorted? And what do you mean by distorted?

Comment: The left Nav expands from top to bottom if I do not put Form tag. However as I put Form tag, it shrinks to just occupy content.

Comment: As an additional info, the problem is with IE only. Div expands well till bottom in Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Problem with IE:
Body has a 100% height and width. When div(s) inside form tag are set to 100%, Firefox and Chrome are able to expand 100%. But with IE, I had to set Form tag too with 100% height and width

```
<Form style="height:100%;width:100%"> ...DIVs ... </form>
```

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are having some "contact us" form or some other form in your html.

**Remove the additional html  tag (in your html) inside the ASP.NET FORM Tag** and see if it makes any difference.

Replace the below code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> //this is asp.net form

    <form name="blunder"> //some html form in your page
        <!-- Some content -->
    </form>

</form>
```

with

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <divname="blunder">
        <!-- Some content -->
    </div>

</form>
```

Thanks.! Hope it helps.!